# get taxonomy list in a page in the wordpress

Tags: categories, taxonomy, list

I have this code in a page in the WP for show new taxonomy

```
<?php
  $terms = get_terms(array(
  'hide_empty' => 'false',
  'orderby'    => 'name',
  'order'      => 'ASC',
  'taxonomy'   => 'mylist' 
 ));

  foreach  ($terms as $category) {
      echo '<div class="col-ms-4">';
         echo '<div class="category-list">';
             echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . ' "><div class="image_wrapper is-image list-image">'. do_shortcode(sprintf('[wp_custom_image_category term_id="%s"]',$category->term_id)). '</div></a>' ;
             echo '<div class="image-category"><h2 class="title-category"><a href=" ' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . ' "> '.$category->name.' </a></h2></div>';
             echo '<div class="category-count"><a>' . $category->count . '</a></div>';
         echo '</div>';
      echo '</div>';
} ?>
```

but this is not working. Do you have an idea to display new taxonomies on the WordPress? Using this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions such as `get_categories` are unique to the post category taxonomy. "Category" is a taxonomy term. If you register your own taxonomies, you need to use [get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) which has similar parameters to your [get_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/) function.

```
$terms = get_terms(array(
   'hide_empty' => false,
   'orderby'    => 'name',
   'order'      => 'ASC',
   'taxonomy'   => 'your-taxonomy' 
));
```

Comment: I edited the above code but did not work and did not display the categories. where is the problem from?

Comment: What is your taxonomy called? Can you post the exact code you used (update your question with the get_terms call)

Comment: my post is updated

Comment: Does it work now (you accepted my answer). If not, then can you run `var_dump($terms);` before the foreach loop. You should see a list of `WP_Term Object`. If you don't then it means the taxonomy name is wrong or that you have an error elsewhere - please check your error_log file, or make sure to turn debugging on with `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in your wp-config.php